# OSX DPI scaling

Tags: macos, font, resolution

Windows has a feature that can make text and GUI objects larger by changing a DPI setting. This helps keeping the monitors native resolution, but still make text and objects larger on screen.

Is there a similar feature on OSX? I'd like things to be more readable but avoid blurring when choosing a different scaled resolution.

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible until now. Apple tried to implement an resolution independent UI in the past but removed it when the first Retina Macs came out.

Comment: Too bad. I think Microsoft really nailed this feature. It works really well and in Windows 10 mosts app react to the changes without a need to logout and login again.

Answer (score 0):

OS/X has high-DPI functionality too, but Apple seems to have decided to disable it for non-Apple display hardware.

A number of places around the web seem to [claim](http://www.fitzweekly.com/2016/03/enable-hidpi-resolutions-in-el-capitan.html) that you can re-enable it with the command below, but this has not worked for me and my 4K TV.

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true
```